# Why does <!--<script> cause a DOM tree break on the browser?

Tags: javascript, dom, html

When I see the answer to solve Level 15 of http://escape.alf.nu, I notice that `<!--<script>` will cause the DOM parser to break. In the following HTML you won't see the string "Test" (tested on IE 11 & Firefox & Chrome):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var a = '<!--<script>';
        </script>
        <p>Test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: DOM tree of the above HTML]

But these two scripts will show "Test":

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var a = '<!--';
        </script>
        <p>Test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var a = '<script>';
        </script>
        <p>Test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't understand, why does this happen?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This raises the important point that the text inside of `<script>` tags on an HTML page is parsed by the HTML parser before it is parsed by the Javascript parser.

This code is not valid HTML5 syntax, so there is nothing in the HTML5 specification that would give us a clue about what is going one here. To be specific, there are two issues:

- There is a `<script>` tag without a closing `</script>`.
- There is an opening `<!--` without a closing `-->`. (see [restrictions for contents of script elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements))

Both of these problem will put a browser's HTML parser into an error parsing mode, which means they are trying to make sense of invalid syntax. What browsers will do when trying to make sense of invalid syntax is *undefined behavior*, which technically means that anything can happen (such as [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)). The *de facto* behavior here seems to be that browsers are agreeing on how they handle this undefined behavior, but it is undefined behavior nonetheless.

For whatever reason, this combination of syntax issues next to each other causes browsers to ignore the text later in the document.

---

EDIT: I have identified how the parsing error is produced by stepping through [this part of the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements).

The text content of the script (excluding whitespace) is

```
var a = '<!--<script>';
```

This must match the following grammar rule:

```
data1 *( escape [ script-start data3 ] "-->" data1 ) [ escape ]
```

We can begin parsing the text content by matching `data1`, which has the following rule:

```
data1         = < any string that doesn't contain a substring that matches not-data1 >
not-data1     = "<!--"
```

That is, the string `var a = '` matches the `data1` production. It ends there because the next part is `<!--`.

For there to be any text afterwards in the script, it must match the `escape` production, which is as follows:

```
escape        = "<!--" data2 *( script-start data3 script-end data2 )
```

Let's match the next part of the text. So far we have

```
data1    var a = '
escape   <!--
  data2  ???
```

Now nothing can be contained in `data2` because the `data2` production prohibits the substring `<script>` (i.e. a `script-start`)!

```
data2         = < any string that doesn't contain a substring that matches not-data2 >
not-data2     = script-start / "-->"
```

The lexer cannot proceed with with valid steps according to the grammar, so the browser must now go into error processing.

Comment: I thought HTML5 specified exactly how error handling was supposed to work?

Comment: @icktoofay You are correct in the fact that HTML5 describes the parsing process precisely and is explicitly more forgiving than HTML 4.01 or XHTML in allowing "tag soup", so to speak. However, if the code is not parsable by the grammar in the HTML5 spec, it's up to the browsers to decide what to do.

Answer (score 2):

It 'll be some assumption being violated in the internal mechanism.

There's not much point trying to rationalise about this stuff.

**[You wrote invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check), so *anything* can happen.**

Comment: By your first sentence, do you mean a bug? I never knew about this. I would have thought that the parser would be smart enough to figure that it was in a string. A bit of a gotcha. Besides '<script>' and comments what else does it apply to? Or am I missing something? (I didn't downvote btw).

Comment: @acarlon: No, I don't mean a bug. Any software algorithm has preconditions and postconditions and it is fair for the software to set its preconditions to match the specification of the inputs. That is, the HTML5 specification. When that specification is violated because the input is _invalid_ (as is the case here), the algorithm's preconditions may be broken, and the results unreliable. In the C++ world we call this "Undefined Behaviour". There _will_ be a way to explain it in detail, but probably only through examining the source code of the rendering engine, which is utterly pointless.

Comment: -1. You are apparently confusing HTML with C++. They are quite different.

Comment: @ruakh: I'm not confusing anything. The principle that computer systems must choose how to handle invalid input is universal and fundamental. Until browsers reject invalid HTML by displaying an error message to the user, they have to make a "best-guess" at rendering and, beyond a few suggestions in the spec (and I've checked — there are none for this) that means it's entirely up to the browser. It's UB. But if you choose to instead read my breakdown of this issue as "hur hur hur ur writing c++ hur hur" then go right ahead: I certainly can't stop you.

Comment: OK, it is just that I would think even the most rudimentary parser would detect a string and ignore everything inside - otherwise a lot of languages (such as c++ since you mentioned it) would be toast. Is it part of the HTML5 spec that certain sequences of characters are not allowed in javascript strings?

Comment: @acarlon: Sure, you could make a browser that did that. _But why?_ It takes cycles. It takes time. It'll slow down your pages. All for invalid input. Make the input compliant, and everything is solved. And, yes, the contents of a `script` tag are controlled in [4.3.1.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements).

Comment: Thanks for the link. OK, I am with you - a tradeoff between implementation and processing time for the browser vs devs shooting themselves in the foot. The instance of these mishaps must be reasonably rare otherwise the number of devs with badly mangled feet would warrant a parser that ignored strings.

Comment: Because all three browsers (IE11, Firefox, and Chrome) behave same way, so I don't think it's bug.

If it's invalid HTML, then please point out why ?

Comment: @gslin: Follow the link in my answer to the W3C validator and find out for yourself! I didn't say it was a bug.

Comment: For the record, I shall edit these comments into the answer, and try to break down `4.3.1.2` a little more, when it's not 4.40am. But, really, I want to teach the idea of "don't spend time on these invalid-input minutiae". Far more useful than analysing browser source code to explain an invalid edge case.

Comment: @acarlon: I vaguely recollect that disallowing certain sequences of chars in hs strings actually is part of the spec: a script tag should be using entities when its content is not in a cdata block.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Re: "I shall edit these comments into the answer, and try to break down `4.3.1.2` a little more": If you CC me when you do that, I may well retract my downvote. The confusion with C++ is still a serious problem with this answer, but at least the answer will also have something useful. (It won't *just* be an expression of confusion with C++.)

Comment: @Denis: On the contrary, when the doctype implies HTML rather than XHTML, entities are *forbidden* inside `<script>` elements. But yes, it's part of the spec that unmatched `<!--` is forbidden inside such elements, too. I guess the fix is to write something like `<\!--` instead.

Comment: @ruakh: Okay will do - didn't get around to it today. Not sure what your fixation with C++ is: the allusion to UB is because this is a fundamental principle of computer software across all specified languages. Besides, I didn't even mention it once in the answer. Please stop asserting that I'm "confused" just because you don't understand what I'm saying!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The notion that "*anything* can happen" is not fundamental or universal; most modern systems do have various safety guarantees, with C and C++ being major and notable exceptions. An invalid HTML document can't make demons fly out the user's nose, like a UB-invoking C or C++ program can.

Comment: @ruakh: Of course it can! If you do _anything_ that the HTML spec does not define, that is -- by definition -- UB. This is not inherent to C++. It is inherent to systems with specified behaviours that do not have infinity pages of specification. Yes, HTML has more safeguards and guidelines on graceful failures; that does not mean you can write _anything_ that looks vaguely like HTML and assume it has well-defined semantics. If you require that we look at this entirely practically, then consider that no C++ compiler _actually_ makes demons fly out of your nose.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Re: "Yes, HTML has more safeguards and guidelines on graceful failures; that does not mean you can write *anything* that looks vaguely like HTML and assume it has well-defined semantics": Exactly right. Like C++, HTML does not guarantee specific behaviors for all invalid inputs (though you're wrong to claim that this is universal: there are plenty of systems that do require input validation and do specify that all validation failures be reported), but unlike C++, HTML does not have a general principle that any invalid input can have any arbitrary outcome.

Comment: @ruakh: C++ does not have that general principle, either, so that final statement is not only wrong but a bit of a strawman. The principle I'm talking about _is_ universal if you look at it broadly enough: any system that specifies that all validation failures be reported, will result in effective undefined behaviour when you try to implement such a system without the physical ability to report a validation failure. It's not even a principle: it's just a basic fact of trying to specify behaviours; unless you've enough space to write infinity words it is physically impossible not to leave gaps.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: O.K., so, with that in mind, please re-read your answer and tell me if you think it's accurate!

Comment: @ruakh: Yes, 100%. Please read _all of my comments above_ to find out why. I do still need to expand it to incorporate some of this discussion, though. Been too busy arguing with people in comment threads ;)

Comment: Actually, I see Peter has now done the full workup in his answer. Not sure I can be bothered now...

Comment: Yeah, I read all of your comments, and none of them supports the claim that "invalid HTML" produces "anything can happen". Especially since you link to a validation page with various errors, most of which have relatively well-defined consequences. Your answer would be a good answer (or at least an acceptable one) if this were a C++ question, but it's not.