# why this small piece of JavaScript breaks?

Tags: javascript

Why this code breaks:

```html
<script>
  var test = "<!-- <script ";
</script>
    
<h1>
  If you can see this it means the page didn't break
</h1>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y3w7ugaw/

and this doesn't

```html
<script>
  var test = "<!-- <script";
</script>
    
<h1>
  If you can see this it means the page didn't break
</h1>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mL1xxygo/

I should not break since `test` var is a string

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942452/why-does-script-cause-a-dom-tree-break-on-the-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. The two examples are not the same in that the first has a space between `<script` and the following closing double quote while the second does not. Both examples have the character sequence `<!--`, used to introduce [comments](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-comments) in HTML source, inside the javascript string.

The first example does not show the header, which can be made to reappear by either

- removing the `<!--` characters, OR
- by removing the space after `<script` in the string value.

The question alluded to in comment states that the HTML is invalid although reading the [HTML parsing spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing) does not make the reason particularly obvious.

A javascript **solution** is to escape characters confusing the parser with a backslash, *even though the character does not normally need escaping*. JavaScript ignores backslashes before ordinary characters whilst the parser does not.

Hence either

```
    var test = "<\!-- <script ";
```

or

```
    var test = "<\!-- <script";
```

both successfully create a string containing the HTML start comment sequence without confusing the parser.